# joomla 1.5 limit maximum characters of title/description

Tags: java, css, joomla, title

How to limit maximum characters of title, description in Joomla 1.5 table?

And how to make if so long, not write all text in table, but write ... or write in other Line.

I mean if title is like:

```
"titleblablablaTITLEblablaTITLEtitle"
```

I want that showed:

```
"titlebl..."
```

or

```
"titleblabl
ablaTITLE
blablaTITL
Etitle"
```

Look to my site at the table 
http://padekime.wu.lt/index.php?option=com_djclassifieds&view=show&cid=1&Itemid=1

```
(Pavadinimas-title) / (Aprasymas-description)
```

Thay are too long table so large, someone could help me? Thank you.

Comment: Are you looking for the CSS `word-break` property? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/word-break

Comment: I really don't know how to use It correct. And I don't think that this is what I need, but maybe... I think I need Word-break (in Aprasymas -Description) after 20 character...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This CSS should do it for you in browsers that support the `word-break` property:

```
td, th {
    word-break: break-all
}
```

If you're interested in a PHP solution, there is a `wordwrap()` function in the standard library:  http://php.net/manual/en/function.wordwrap.php

Comment: That works, but now not "Katergorija", "Pridėtas" columns are so narrow...  Something wrong, look: http://padekime.wu.lt/index.php?option=com_djclassifieds&view=show&cid=1&Itemid=1

I need to make much lower first column (pavadinimas)

Comment: You could narrow down the application of that property to only `td`s of a specific class (eg. `td.name, td.description` instead of `td, th`).  Or add a `min-width` to some of the other classes.